# Preventing services from starting automatically on EC2 Backup Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Windows EC2 instance.  I want to create a backup instance in a different availability zone.  I have found numerous articles explaining how this is done (i.e. Create AMI and launch in new availability zone).

My instance runs about 40 windows services.  And many of these services query various datasource and send out notifications (SMS messages, emails, mobile device notifications).  My fear is when I start up my "Backup Instance" it could start sending out messages that my production server has already sent.  So I am looking for some way to have the services disabled when the backup server is started.

One workaround I thought was to set all services to "Manual" startup mode (vs. "Automatic").  And then create the AMI.  I guess this would work.  But then it also means on a server reboot I would need to go and manually start the services (a pain).

Another was to modify the security groups and basically shut down all connectivity except for Remote Desktop.  This way the services could start but they would not be able to send out their notifications.

Is it possible to configure a security group so that essentially all it can do with the internet is Remote Desktop?

Does anyone else have suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily automate disabling a service via [sc config](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc990290%28v=ws.11%29.aspx):

```
sc config ServiceName start= disabled
```

In the same script, you can use [AWS Tools for PowerShell](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/) to create the AMI via [New-EC2Image](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/reference/items/New-EC2Image.html). You could then poll image status until it is complete and then set the services back to `start = auto` on the instance you used to create the AMI.

---

The best route would be to sidestep this problem entirely. I'm suspect of the value of this "*hot-but-actually-not*" style of backup; if you're not intervening manually during a failure, you'll have to write some automation to handle the service startup, switching environments, etc. That isn't counting the time it takes to boot 40 windows services. Concerning your alternate suggestion, changing security groups or security group rules during cutover would complicate that further.

You may be better served by simply placing your production instance in an [AutoScaling Group](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) of min/max/desired size 1, with an [ELB health check](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-healthchecks.html) that you can point to any service endpoint on your instance. For example, you could point it at service that then checks the status of all other services on that same box and returns HTTP 200. If anything happens to your currently running instance that causes the health check to fail and be taken out of service on the ELB, a new instance based on your backup AMI will be launched.

The AMI you take would be used for the launch config, so that any new instances that are spun up in case of failure would be from the backup. You can periodically create new launch configurations based on newer AMIs (as you add more services, perform windows updates, etc...) and swap those into the AutoScaling group without impacting the currently running instance.

Comment: Thank you.  Here is approach I took: 1) run script to change startup mode to "Manual" for all my services using scconfig.  2) Create Image.  3) Run script to change them back to Auto.